# MySQL: Grouping from inside INNER JOINs

Tags: mysql, sql, ansi-sql

MySQL 5.6 here. I have the following tables:

```
DESCRIBE profiles;
+----------------------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field                      | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------------------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| profile_id                 | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| profile_given_name         | varchar(100)        | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| profile_surname            | varchar(100)        | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
+----------------------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

describe friendships;
+----------------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field                | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| friendship_id        | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| requester_profile_id | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| recipient_profile_id | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
+----------------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

The `profiles` table represents users of a system, and `friendships` represents a many-to-many relationship of which users are friends with which other users. When a user/profile sends a "Friend Request" to a user, they are considered to be the`requester` in of the friendship. Conversely, those who receive Friend Requests from others are the `recipients`.

I'm trying to write a (seemingly) simple ANSI-compliant `SELECT` that tells me all the profiles a particular profile is friends with, regardless of whether they were the `requester` or the `recipient` of the friendship.

To set the DB up with some data:

```
INSERT INTO friendships (
  friendship_ref_id,
  requester_profile_id,
  recipient_profile_id
) VALUES (
  '01234',
  2,
  1
), (
  '67890',
  1,
  3  
), (
  '78901',
  1,
  4
), (
  '89012',
  2,
  3
), (
  '90123',
  3,
  4
);
```

Then my best attempt thus far:

```
SELECT      f.requester_profile_id,
            f.recipient_profile_id
FROM        profiles p
INNER JOIN  friendships f
ON (
    f.requester_profile_id = p.profile_id
    OR
    f.recipient_profile_id = p.profile_id
)
WHERE       p.profile_id = 1;
```

When I run this I get:

```
+----------------------+----------------------+
| requester_profile_id | recipient_profile_id |
+----------------------+----------------------+
|                    1 |                    2 |
|                    1 |                    3 |
|                    1 |                    4 |
|                    2 |                    1 |
+----------------------+----------------------+
```

But what I *really* want is a single column composed of all the `DISTINCT` profile IDs (requester and recipient alike) that `profile_id = 1` is friends with, something like:

```
+----------------------+
|      profile_friends |
+----------------------+
|                    2 |
|                    3 |
|                    4 |
+----------------------+
```

...since `profile_id = 1` is friends with `profile_id IN { 2, 3, 4 }`, etc.

**What am I missing here to make the query work?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two options here.

The first uses a CASE to decide which column to use for each result:

```
SELECT     
   CASE WHEN f.requester_profile_id = p.profile_id THEN f.recipient_profile_id 
        ELSE f.requester_profile_id END as profile_friends
FROM        profiles p
INNER JOIN  friendships f
  /* Original ON clause would still work, but I prefer the briefer syntax */
ON p.profile_id IN (f.requester_profile_id,f.recipient_profile_id)
WHERE       p.profile_id = 1;
```

The second UNIONs two SELECT statements together, where one checks requester and the other checks recipient:

```
SELECT      f.recipient_profile_id as profile_friends
FROM        profiles p
INNER JOIN  friendships f
ON f.requester_profile_id = p.profile_id
WHERE       p.profile_id = 1

UNION

SELECT      f.requester_profile_id
FROM        profiles p
INNER JOIN  friendships f
ON  f.recipient_profile_id = p.profile_id
WHERE       p.profile_id = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

I would be inclined to do this using `exists`:

```
select p.*
from profiles p
where exists (select 1
              from friendships f
              where f.requester_profile_id = p.profile_id and 
                    f.recipient_profile_id = 1
             ) or
             (select 1
              from friendships f
              where f.recipient_profile_id = p.profile_id and 
                    f.requester_profile_id = 1
             );
```

This query should have two indexes:  `friendships(recipient_profile_id, requester_profile_id)` and `friendships(requester_profile_id, recipient_profile_id)`.